# multithreaded code with released GIL and complex threads is slower in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, numba

I am working on a 8 core processor machine with 8G RAM and Linux Redhat 7 and I am using Pycharm IDE.

I tried to use python threading module to take the advantage of multi-core processing but I ended up with a much slower code. I released the GIL through Numba and made sure my threads are doing sufficiently complex calculations so the problem is not what discussed in  for example [How to make numba @jit use all cpu cores (parallelize numba @jit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610292/how-to-make-numba-jit-use-all-cpu-cores-parallelize-numba-jit)

Here is the multi threaded code:

```
l=200

@nb.jit('void(f8[:],f8,i4,f8[:])',nopython=True,nogil=True)
def force(r,ri,i,F):

   sum=0
   for j in range(12):
       if (j != i):
           fij=-4 * (12*1**12/(r[j]-ri)**13-6*1**6/(r[j]-ri)**7)
           sum=sum+fij

   F[i+12]=sum

def ODEfunction(r, t):

   f = np.zeros(2 * 12)

   lbound=-4* (12*1**12/(-0.5*l-r[0])**13-6*1**6/(-0.5*l-r[0])**7)
   rbound=-4* (12*1**12/(0.5*l-r[12-1])**13-6*1**6/(0.5*l-r[12-1])**7)

   f[0:12]=r[12:2*12]

   thlist=[threading.Thread(target=force, args=(r,r[i],i,f)) for i in range(12)]

   for thread in thlist:
       thread.start()
   for thread in thlist:
       thread.join()

   f[12]=f[12]+lbound
   f[2*12-1]=f[2*12-1]+rbound
   return f
```

And this is the sequential version:

```
l=200

@nb.autojit()
def ODEfunction(r, t):

   f = np.zeros(2 * 12)
   lbound=-4* (12*1**12/(-0.5*l-r[0])**13-6*1**6/(-0.5*l-r[0])**7)
   rbound=-4* (12*1**12/(0.5*l-r[12-1])**13-6*1**6/(0.5*l-r[12-1])**7)

   f[0:12]=r[12:2*12]

   for i in range(12):
       fi = 0.0
       for j in range(12):
           if (j!=i):
               fij = -4 * (12*1**12/(r[j]-r[i])**13-6*1**6/(r[j]-r[i])**7)
               fi = fi + fij
       f[i+12]=fi
   f[12]=f[12]+lbound
   f[2*12-1]=f[2*12-1]+rbound
   return f
```

I also thought to attach an image of the system monitor during the run of the multi-threaded and the sequential code:

[System Motinor during the run of the multi threaded code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOEar.png)

[System Motinor during the run of the sequential code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iX4M.png)

Does anybody know what can be the reason for this inefficiency in threaded code?

Comment: Possibly because you're writing to a shared array from all of the threads? I don't know if Numba is inserting a lock around every access to the array to make that work, but if so, that's one potential problem. If not, it may just be that your striding causes false sharing—slots written by different threads end up on the same cache line, so they're constantly invalidating each others' caches.

Comment: Why don't you use Numbas prange? eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224982/4045774 But nevertheless I didn't expect a speedup here. The whole function is just to simple (only a few thousand operations)

Answer (score 2):

You must be aware, that calling a function in Python is quite costly (compared for example to calling a function in C) even more so calling a numba-jitted function: It must be checked, that the parameters are right (i.e. that they are really float-numpy-arrays you are passing - we will see that it can be factor 5  slower than a normal Python-call).

Let's check the overhead of your jitted function, compared to the work happening in the function:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit('void(f8[:],f8,i4,f8[:])',nopython=True,nogil=True)
def force(r,ri,i,F):

   sum=0
   for j in range(12):
       if (j != i):
           fij=-4 * (12*1**12/(r[j]-ri)**13-6*1**6/(r[j]-ri)**7)
           sum=sum+fij

   F[i+12]=sum

@nb.jit('void(f8[:],f8,i4,f8[:])',nopython=True,nogil=True)
def nothing(r,ri,i,F):
    pass

def no_jit(r,ri,i,F):
    pass

F=np.zeros(24)
r=np.zeros(12)
```

And now:

```
>>>%timeit force(r,1.0,0,F)
706 ns ± 8.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit nothing(r,1.0,0,F)
645 ns ± 5.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit no_jit(r,1.0,0,F) #to measure overhead of numba
120 ns ± 6.56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

So there are basically 90% overhead, which you don't have in the single-threaded mode because the function is "inlined". This is not surprisingly: your for-loop has only 12 iterations - it is just not enough work, for example in the example your have linked the inner loop has `10^10` iterations!

Additionally, there is also some overhead from dispatching the work between threads, my guts say it is even more than the overhead from the jitted-call - but to be sure one should profile the program. These odds are quite hard to beat even with 8 cores!

The largest road-blocker right now is probably the big overhead of the `force`-call compared to the time spent in the function itself. The analysis above is quite superficial so I don't guarantee there are no other significant issues - but to having bigger chunks of work for `force` would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Yes I think that the force call takes most of the time but I don't know about anyway to do multi-threading without calling a function! Actually I followed the guide by  How to make numba @jit use all cpu cores (parallelize numba @jit). They also call a function for multi threading but their call doesn't take so much of the time so I am wondering why my function call takes so much time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610292/how-to-make-numba-jit-use-all-cpu-cores-parallelize-numba-jit

Comment: @Arash Their call takes as much time as yours, but in the loop they have much more work(10^10 iterations) so the overhead is not important. Your function makes only 12 iterations - it is not enough to justify the overhead

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you for your help. As a final question do you expect that the C or Fortran version of this code doesn't have this problem. Because you said that in Python the call takes so much of the time.

Comment: You can use prange, this  would also eliminate the need of function calls, however whether it will speed-up your code is unclear. @Arash